# Angular how to make a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a view that I want the view the to get newly updated price everytime I click the change price button. I used a service that stores the newPrice that gets his value from the priceModel. so far I can't get the price to updated in the DOM when i press the button.

this is my html

```
    <body ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="my-controller">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="priceModel" />
    <br/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changePrice()">Change Price</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='priceController'>
    Price {{price}}
  </div>

</body>
```

this is my javascript

```
    var app = angular.module('my-app', [])

.controller("my-controller", function($scope, Products) {

  var newPrice = '';

  $scope.changePrice = function(){
    newPrice = $scope.priceModel;
    Products.price(newPrice);
  }

})

.controller('priceController', function(Products, $scope){
  $scope.price = Products.price();
})

.service('Products', function(){

  this.price = function(newPrice){
    return newPrice;
  };

})
```

[**MY CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/candoa/pen/aOMGOx)

Comment: so why do not you assign newPrice to any variable within Product Service? You simply need to define a setter and getter methods that work with a local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could maintain a object inside the service so that you could follow the **dot rule**(JavaScript inheritance) to update the object values.

Create and price object inside a service and there would be an setter method that would set the new value of an `price.value` & that could be sharable among different controller.

In order to make it working inside a `priceController` you need to set whole price object to `$scope.price` like by doing `$scope.price = Products.price;` that will take care of updation of `price.value`. HTML will have and `{{price.value}}`

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="my-controller">
    <h1>Products</h1>
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" />
    <br/>
    <button type="button" ng-click="changePrice(price)">Change Price</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='priceController'>
    Price {{price.value}}
  </div>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', [])

.controller("my-controller", function($scope, Products) {

  $scope.price = Products.price.value;
  $scope.changePrice = function(newPrice){
    Products.setPrice(newPrice);
  };
})
.controller('priceController', function(Products, $scope){
  $scope.price = Products.price;
})
.service('Products', function(){
  var Products = this;
  Products.price = {
    value: ''
  };
  this.setPrice = function(newPrice){
    Products.price.value = newPrice;
  };  
})
```

[**Working Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXVdML)

Answer (score 0):

In service, you have to return object out of the function like this

```
app.module('my-app').service('Products', function(){
  var price = 0;
  return {
    setPrice: function(price){
      price = price;
    },
    getPrice: function(){
      return price;
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your $scope.changePrice function in your controller

```
$scope.changePrice = function(){
  Product.setPrice($scope.priceModel);
}
```

When user press the button, this function will be called and pass "priceModel" to function "setPrice" in Product service

And to watch for changing on "price" value on service, you can use $watch like this

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return Product.getPrice() }, function(newVal, oldVal){
  if(newVal){
    $scope.price = newVal;
  }
});
```